# Recording selenium tests and running them from Java

Tags: java, testing, selenium

Is there an existing for loading *recorded* Selenium tests and running them from Java? The only two main constrictions are:

1. Tests are recorded in Selenium IDE (v 1.5),
2. Tests can be called from Java (or more specifically JUnit or TestNG).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save a test suite in Selenium IDE (it will it will contain information about test cases) and run it with [Selenium Server Standalone](http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-server-standalone-2.15.0.jar).

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.15.0.jar -htmlsuite "*firefox" "http://yourpage.com" "path/to/testsuite" "path/to/result.html"
```

Answer (score 0):

Tests recorded in Selenium IDE can be exported to Java using JUnit assertions. See http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#test-case-pane